# C++ silently assigns a wrong type to an array element via an alias pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, polymorphism

Here's the reduced code with the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout<<"A::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};
struct B : A {
    void foo() {
        cout<<"B::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};
struct C : A {
    void foo() {
        cout<<"C::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b[3];
    A* a = b;
    C c;
    a[1] = c;   //what's happening here??
    a[1].foo(); //prints B::foo() when virtual, and A::foo() when non-virtual
}
```

My question is not related to dynamic or static polymorphism, but rather the strange assignment  with the line `a[1] = c;` which seems to have totally no effect. If `a` is an alias to the array `b`, then that assignment should give at least a warning, which is absent while compiling with GCC-10.
Could anyone please clarify what's the compiler up to in that line?

Comment: `a[1] = c;   //what's happening here??` Undefined behavior (due to `a[1]`).

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the comment, could you please link any reference to have somewhat formal justification to this your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[1] = c;`

There is [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) in this line and undefined behavior.

Type of the `a[1]` is `A`, so object of type `C` sliced to the object of type `A`.

`a[1].foo(); //prints B::foo() when virtual, and A::foo() when non-virtual`

`B::foo()` printed because assignment operator don't change the type of object, so it will not copy pointer to `vtable`. `vptr` will point to the `B::foo()`.

If you construct new object of type `C` in place of the old one, you will change `vptr` and function `C::foo()` will be called.

Just for illustration, don't do it in real code: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/TvDqrh)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout<<"A::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};
struct B : A {
    void foo() {
        cout<<"B::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};
struct C : A {
    void foo() {
        cout<<"C::foo()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b[3];
    A* a = b;
    C c;

// Everything below is undefined behavior and works in this example only because of struct size equality.

    a[1] = c;   // object slicing and undefined behavior. vptr still points to vtable of B
    a[1].foo(); // B::foo()
    new(b) C;   // creating new object in memory ob b[0] with vptr to vtable of C
    a[0].foo(); // C::foo()
}
```

There is no warning, because object slicing is valid operation. It can be done intentionally.

Comment: thanks for the insights, explains quite a lot of things! But could you please elaborate on what you mean exactly (with the exact command line) by ```If you construct new object of type C in place of the old one, you will change vptr and function C::foo() will be called.``` ?

Comment: Construct a new object in my example is `new(b) C;`
This is placement new operator. It doesn't allocates memory, but uses pointer to already allocated memory and calls ctor on that memory. This line creates a new C object in the memory of b[0]. In this example all structs have the same size and this is safe, but it's not safe in production code.
In ctor of C class vptr will be assigned and will point to the vtable of class C. vptr assigned only in ctors.
`A* a = b;` `a` is a pointer to base class. When you call virtual function by a pointer, it will be called through vptr->vtable->function.

Comment: but `a[1]` is UB. it seems to works as B doesn't have extra members.

Comment: Yes, it's UB, and I two times focuses attention on the fact, that this works only because size of the structs is the same.
The question was "what is happening?" and not "how to make it work?". But you are right, it's is not safe at all to use such code.

Comment: sorry, but what's UB ?

Comment: Undefined Behavior
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: I won't say comment in example code as focuses attention (added in edit to add example). you focused on object slicing IMO. Having it in regular text as now is far better :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed answer to clarify, that this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

From [operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators) (emphasize mine)

> - In any case, if the pointed-to type is different from the array element type, disregarding cv qualifications, at every level if the elements are themselves pointers, the behavior of pointer arithmetic is undefined. **In particular, pointer arithmetic with pointer to base, which is pointing at an element of an array of derived objects is undefined**.

so `a[1]` (which is equivalent to `*(a + 1)`) is undefined behavior.

You might do pointer arithmetic on `b`:

```
A* b1 = &b[1]; // OK
*b1 = c; // OK, but object slicing
```

even better, reference instead of pointer (no nullptr check, and pointer arithmetic is discouraged):

```
A& b1 = b[1]; // OK
b1 = c; // OK, but object slicing
```

Comment: I appreciate your reference and emphasize, really awesome so I need to read more about...

Answer (score 1):

Since 'a' is a pointer to the base class A it cannot be assigned values by using the indexing concept. Variable 'a' can only point to the starting of the array or it can point to the address of a single variable.

In the above case if you want to assign variable 'c' then you can assign the address of c by the following code, which will print the **C::foo()** as the output.

```
  a = &c;   
  a->foo();
```

Comment: as you've stated, ```Variable 'a' can only point to the starting of the array or it can point to the address of a single variable``` - so I'm trying to get use of the first option and getting an unexpected result for me while trying to operate on a cell of that array.